# Парсинг xml и теги

Tags: java, xml, api

При парсинге локального xml документа с тегом `DOCTYPE mvideo_xml SYSTEM "http://api.mvideo.ru/api/mobile/v03/public/category.dtd"` возникает ошибка доступа:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:
>   http://api.mvideo.ru/api/mobile/v03/public/category.dtd.

Как можно ее игнорировать и прочитать остальные данные?

Comment: может так? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references

Comment: Большинство xml-парсеров имеют настройку, которая позволяет запретить обработку DTD.